# Pattern in Squared Numbers and their Digit Sum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation, pattern-recognition, sums-of-squares

So this has been boggling my mind for some time now. On spring break I was really bored and started messing around with numbers when I noticed something. I was squaring each number (1-9) when I realized I could get the products down to a single digit using the digit sum.
1^2=1 | 1^3=1 | 1^4=1...
2^2=4 | 2^3=8 | 2^4=16=1+6=7...
3^2=9 | 3^3=27=2+7=9...
4^2=16=1+6=7...
5^2=25=2+5=7...
6^2=36=3+6=9...
7^2=49=4+9=13=1+3=4...
8^2=64=6+4=10=1...
9^2=81=8+1=9...
So on and so forth. I realized there was many patterns were emerging.
    X |x^2|x^3|x^4|x^5|x^6|x^7
1 = 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 = 2 | 4 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 7 | 5
3 = 3 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9
4 = 4 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 7
5 = 5 | 7 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 4 | 2
6 = 6 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9
7 = 7 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 4
8 = 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 8
9 = 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9
[(The numbers follow these patterns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUnZS.jpg)

[image]

[without 3, 6, or 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLqHb.jpg)
[image]

[ebb and flow of numbers squared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEeOv.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Spring break is not what it used to be ...

Comment: The repeated application of the digit sum of a number will yield what the remainder of the original number is when divided by nine.  What you have in effect discovered is the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $(\mathbb{Z}_9,+,\times)$ and in particular the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $(\mathbb{Z}_9^*, \times)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you take the repeated digit sum you are finding the remainder on division by $9$ except you are getting $9$ instead of $0$.  This is the classic [divisibility test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9) for $9$.  When you take the powers, you are effectively doing that $\bmod 9$.  That shows why you get stuck with $3,6,9.$  Once you square it you have two factors of $3$ and every successive power is also divisible by $9$.  $\bmod 9$ we have $8 \equiv -1$, so when you square $8$ you get $1$, then another multiply gets $8$ and so on.

The numbers coprime to $9$, of which there are $\phi(9)=6,$ form a multiplcative group.  Each one will cycle with a period that divides into $6$.